# Shorten or replace links created using asp:repeater and Buildlink(Eval

Tags: asp.net

I have a table of data. One of the fields on the table has a link created using an ASP:Repeater, then buildlink(eval. Code is posted below. The links are much too long and make the table too wide and ugly. I'd like to replace the link with a different word, as simple as "Link Here" Maybe. Or, just shorten the link somehow... Any info is helpful, I am trying to learn as much as I can.

Here's the code that creates the link I want to shorten or replace.

```
<%# BuildLink(Eval("TaskDefinition.Url").ToString(), Eval("TaskInstanceID").ToString())%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
<a href='<% =BuildLink(Eval("TaskDefinition.Url").ToString(), Eval("TaskInstanceID").ToString())%>' >My Link</a>
```

Just edited, please copy/paste and try

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server"  
NavigateUrl='<%# BuildLink(Eval("TaskDefinition.Url").ToString(), Eval("TaskInstanceID").ToString())%>'>
 My Link    
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it only adds ">My Link" to the end of the actual link. Any other ideas or know why it doesn't work like you intended?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the <%# used for data binding, can you just use 
<br> <%= instead?

Comment: So you mean doing this?

<a href='<br><%= BuildLink(Eval("TaskDefinition.Url").ToString(), Eval("TaskInstanceID").ToString())%></br>' >My Link</a>

OR what? Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: This errors out with this error "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control."

Comment: Thanks Yuri, it does work. I just need to make it so that if there isn't a link stored, which is the case on some of these, that it doesn't provide the "My Link" link. Which leads to no where in that situation.